# How many $T_1$ topologies can be constructed on a finite set with n elements?

Tags: general-topology

The problem is about the total number of topologies on a finite set. How many $T_1$ topologies can be constructed on a finite set with n elements?

Comment: What is the answer for $n=1,2$ can you generalise and use induction?

Answer (score 11):

If the topology is $T_1$, then singletons are closed. Since the set is finite, any subset is a finite union of closed sets. It follows that all subsets are closed. Therefore the only possible topology is the discrete topology.

Comment: not getting ...please explain

Comment: What conclusion do you draw from the last sentence?

Comment: ohh sorry.... it is $2^n$ many righy?

Comment: @EuReka note that the finite union of closed sets is closed, and the complement of a closed set is open.

Comment: @EuReka Let $A \subset X$. Put $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \{x_i\}$. Each $\{x_i\}$ is closed. What can you say about $A$?

Comment: please elaborate and give me a proper answer

Comment: Ayman shows in fact that *every* set is closed if the underlying set is finite and its topology is $T_1$. How many topologies can you find having that property?

Comment: @EuReka Clear now? See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Two topologies are different if and only if a set can be found that belongs to exactly one of them.